# activeQt fails to open *.xls if the Excel.Application is not visible

Tags: c++, excel, qt, activeqt

when trying to open a *.xls file using activeQt and the code:

```
QAxObject *excel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application", this);
QAxObject *workbooks = excel->querySubObject("Workbooks");
QAxObject *workbook = workbooks->querySubObject("Open(const QString&)", "c:\\somefile.xls");
QAxObject *worksheets = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets");
QAxObject *worksheet = worksheets->querySubObject("Item(int)", 1);
```

I get an error:

> QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member Open: Unknown error
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.

I have searched the internet and found out that if the `excel` has the property `Visible` set to `true`, everything gonna workout smoothly with no error.
the funny part is that i have to set this property before opening the file otherwise the program gonna crush. However if I set it to `true` after opening the file, the excel app will show up correctly (showing me the data in the file) but the program will crush.

I am looking for a real solution, or the cause of the problem. I don't want the `excel` to be visible to the user at anytime.

so making it visible and then invisible is not a satisfying solution for me

*p.s. the same code used to work 100% correctly for a whole month on my laptop, and then it started to crush. On my workplace they have the same problem on a pc, so my coworker used to run his apps on my pc to check if they work. it is a bad habit since we don't know what the situation will be for the user*

I am using Qt 5.8.0, MS office 2016 and MS office 2012.

Comment: no solution yet for this problem! still struglling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution long time ago, sorry for not updating.

The whole problem was because of the Foxit Pro plugin. I deactivated it in MS office and everything worked fine.

P.S. the problem could be in any MS office application, make sure to turn it off befor using the COM api.